# (CI 4) How to redirect within Controller?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

how can I refer to another within one controller? In **CI3** (for example in the controller client.php) I solved this as follows:

```
redirect('/Clients', 'refresh');
```

but that no longer seems to work in CI4. (Msg: "route cannot be found while reverse-routing.")
I Also tried

```
redirect()->route('/Clients');
```

but the error is the same.

```
redirect()->to('/Clients');
```

redirects nowhere (no output, nothing)

For a better understanding: I want to use a controller (e.g. Clients/create to Clients/details)

Answer (score 3):

What you should notice is that `redirect()` does not just set headers like it used to do in CI3. In CI4 it returns a RedirectResponse object with which you can ask your controller to do a redirection.
To do so, you need to **return** this RedirectResponse object inside your controller. Without the return statement, the redirection won't happen.

An other thing to notice is that `redirect()` can be called with some "options" :

### Going to a named route

```
return redirect()->route('named_route');
```

**or**

```
 return redirect('named_route');
```

To use this, you need to add a named routes in your `app/Config/Routes.php` file :

```
$routes->get('/', 'MyController::index', ['as' => 'named_route']);
```

### Going to a specific URI

```
return redirect()->to('Clients');
```

It will redirect you to your base url with */Clients* at the end.

Please check out the doc for further informations : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

@ViLar gives the correct answer, but it's important to note that when using auto routing the CI3 version `redirect('home');` becomes `return redirect()->to('home');`

It's confusing to just say "Going to a specific URI" and omit that this means auto routed controllers.