# Ci4 redirecting routes

Tags: routes, codeigniter-4

I am trying to use redirect in Ci4 and it is not working (loading an empty white page)

In the controller i use the redirect function as follows: `redirect()->to('login')`

And in the routes.php file i have the route named as follows: `$routes->get('login', "Home::login");`

When i go with the browser directly to where i should land the page is loaded so it is not a page problem.
Secondly in the debug bar since i am in development in the routes tab i can see the route defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(CI 4) How to redirect within Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969223/ci-4-how-to-redirect-within-controller)

Comment: Duplicate: [CodeIgniter 4 redirect function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707864/codeigniter-4-redirect-function-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

I have omitted `return` and additionally (for whoever lands here) if you are finding index.php in the uri and you are using mod_rewrite be sure that in app.php you have `public $indexPage = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Please use below format to redirect to the routes path

**Routes.php**

```
$routes->get('/login', 'Home::login');
```

**Within Controller function Use Below format.**

```
 return redirect()->route('login');
```